# Why my program doesn't work?

Tags: c, debugging, cryptography

I'm creating my first C Program, this program must crypt your password. But there's a problem: give me many error, But I don't know how to fix it.
Anyone could fix it and say me why my program doesn't run?
These are the errors:

```
psw-crypter.C: In function ‘void cripta_password()’:
psw-crypter.C:6:41: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int*’, but argument 2 has type ‘char*’ [-Wformat=]
                 int psw = scanf("%d", &i);
                                         ^
psw-crypter.C: In function ‘int main()’:
psw-crypter.C:18:26: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int*’, but argument 2 has type ‘char*’ [-Wformat=]
  int psw = scanf("%d", &i);
                          ^
psw-crypter.C:19:23: error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)()’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
  int passwordfinale = cripta_password;
                       ^
```

..and this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


void cripta_password() {
        char i;
        int psw = scanf("%d", &i);
        int psw1 = psw %  10;
        for(int number = psw1; number < psw1;psw1++) {
        int psw2 = psw1 * psw1;
        int psw3 = psw2 % psw1;
        int pswcript = psw3 + 3.14;
}
}

int main() {
printf("Cripta la tua password!");
char i;
int psw = scanf("%d", &i);
int passwordfinale = cripta_password;
printf("La tua password completa è:");
printf("%d", passwordfinale);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a lot of mistakes in your code. I suggest to make a c tutorial first. You must understand what you write. Your code looks more as try and error. I don't think it's helpfull for you if someone gives you a working code.

Comment: Yeah I've answered but after reading I saw his horrible mistakes, shame to ask this kind of question...

Answer (score 2):

Ok I don't answer directly this question but first clean up your mistakes :

1/ Indent (it's for help).

2/ Remove unused code.

3/ Pointer function unused -> remove.

4/ Add return type int as expected, and return statement.

5/ Correct type

6/ Loop limit : here you loop through int (2^32), I can't correct as I don't know what you do.

7/ Add careful when add float and int...

```
#include <stdio.h>

// #4 void cripta_password() {
int cripta_password() {
    // #5 char i;
    int i;
    int psw = scanf("%d", &i);
    int psw1 = psw %  10;
    // #6 you loop throught int (2^32)
    for(int number = psw1; number < psw1;psw1++) {
        int psw2 = psw1 * psw1;
        int psw3 = psw2 % psw1;
        // #7 cast addition int + float...
        int pswcript = psw3 + 3.14;
    }
    return 1; // #6 return your int var
}

int main() {
    printf("Cripta la tua password!");
    // #2 char i;
    // #2 int psw = scanf("%d", &i);
    // #3 int passwordfinale = cripta_password;
    printf("La tua password completa è:");
    printf("%d", cripta_password()); // #3 passwordfinale);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We got warnings:

```
$ gcc crypt.c 
crypt.c: In function ‘cripta_password’:
crypt.c:6:25: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat=]
         int psw = scanf("%d", &i);
                         ^
crypt.c: In function ‘main’:
crypt.c:18:17: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat=]
 int psw = scanf("%d", &i);
                 ^
crypt.c:19:22: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 int passwordfinale = cripta_password;
```

Just fix the warnings and call your function properly and use correct types for everything:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int cripta_password() {
    char i;
    int pswcript;
    int psw = scanf("%c", &i);
    int psw1 = psw % 10;
    for (int number = psw1; number < psw1; psw1++) {
        int psw2 = psw1 * psw1;
        int psw3 = psw2 % psw1;
        pswcript = psw3 + 3.14;
    }
    return pswcript;
}

int main() {
    printf("Cripta la tua password!");
    char i;
    int psw = scanf("%c", &i);
    int passwordfinale = cripta_password();
    printf("La tua password completa è:");
    printf("%d", passwordfinale);
}
```

Now test it:

```
crypta
Cripta la tua password!niklas
La tua password completa è:23
Process finished with exit code 0
```

The errors you had mean:

```
psw-crypter.C: In function ‘void cripta_password()’:
psw-crypter.C:6:41: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int*’, but argument 2 has type ‘char*’ [-Wformat=]
                 int psw = scanf("%d", &i);
```

= wrong type. Just be consistent with types. You can sometimes interchange `char` and `int` for special cases (like encryption) but you must please the compiler. The next warning is the same, the types don't match:

```
                                         ^
psw-crypter.C: In function ‘int main()’:
psw-crypter.C:18:26: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int*’, but argument 2 has type ‘char*’ [-Wformat=]
  int psw = scanf("%d", &i);
```

Then the following error is important. Your function has to return a value if you evaulate the function as a value. You wrote `void`, you can't evaluate a `void` function because `void` means that you don't get a value from the function. I changed it and put in a return statement instead.

```
                          ^
psw-crypter.C:19:23: error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)()’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
  int passwordfinale = cripta_password;
```

Comment: He needs to follow C tutorials.

Comment: @Programmer400 "If it builds it works" is not a good mantra for C.

Answer (score 1):

look at this:

```
int passwordfinale = cripta_password;
```

this statement makes not much sense because:

1. **cripta_password** is a method so you should do `cripta_password()`
2. the method **cripta_password** return void... so you can not assign a void to an int.

fixing the code can be like

```
int cripta_password() {
        char i;
        int psw = scanf("%d", &i);
        int psw1 = psw %  10;
        for(int number = psw1; number < psw1;psw1++) {
        int psw2 = psw1 * psw1;
        int psw3 = psw2 % psw1;
        int pswcript = psw3 + 3.14;
        return pswcript;
}
```

and then after that

```
int main() {
    printf("Cripta la tua password!");
    char i;
    int psw = scanf("%d", &i);
    int passwordfinale = cripta_password();
    printf("La tua password completa è:");
    printf("%d", passwordfinale);
}
```